# How to display a TimeSpan in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I have a duration in seconds of a video and I would like to display that duration in Razor.

Currently I am using

```
@TimeSpan.FromSeconds(item.Duration).ToString()
```

However the rest of the code I am using uses

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
```

Is there way to get the duration (currently an int) to display a as a timespan? using the `@Html.DisplayFor` syntax. The item.duration is pulling form a Entity Framework model which is held as a int in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend your model class using a [`partial class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) definition.

```
public partial class My_class_that_has_been_created_by_EF {
    public string Timespan {
        get { 
            return Timespan.FromSeconds(Duration).ToString(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your view with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Timespan)
```

Answer (score 13):

John,

Create your own display template. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Create a folder called DisplayTemplates under Views/Shared
2. Under that new folder, create a partial view called TimeSpan.cshtml
3. Now, in your view, anytime you encounter a model property that is a timespan, it will automatically be rendered by the TimeSpan DisplayTemplate.
4. Add a new get property to your model.

Model edit (add the following):

```
public TimeSpan MyTimeSpanProperty
{
    get
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration);
    }
}
```

TimeSpan.cshtml

```
@model TimeSpan
@string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", Model.Hours, Model.Minutes, Model.Seconds)
```

Invoked in your view as

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyTimeSpanProperty)
```

This will display as `3:24:16` etc..

That's all there is to it (tho it assumes that you'll pass in a property of type TimeSpan, so if possible, see if you can make that minor change to your model !! )

Comment: Just to add to this. make the format line in the `TimeSpan.cshtml` to `"{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}"` to make sure you've got the double digit padding for the minutes and seconds. `1:4:7` becomes `1:04:07`

Comment: The format 00:00:00 appears to be the default format "DisplayFor". To make sure you're actually affecting the display you may want to use some different characters to make sure you're not just seeing default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of `DataAnnotations` namespace and `DisplayTemplates` in ASP.NET MVC

1. First mask your property with `UIHint` Attribute and set the template to `VideoDuration` in *Models/YourVideoModel.cs*

   ```
   [UIHint("VideoDuration")]
   public int Duration { get; set; }
   ```
2. Add a display template to your project at *Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/**VideoDuration**.cshtml* (you may need to add folder `DisplayTemplates` if it not present)

   ```
   @model int?
   @string.Format("{0:g}", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Model))
   ```

Then you can use it in your view like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Duration)
```