# Formatting TimeSpan - MVC C# Razor DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, timespan, displayfor

I have DisplayFor showing a TimeSpan-value (Duration) in this format:
35.04:08:43.2470000 (dd.HH:mm:ss.fffffff).

My goal is a human-readable string "HH:mm" so I followed [How to display a TimeSpan in MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229365/how-to-display-a-timespan-in-mvc-razor)  and 
tried making a DisplayTemplate in ~views/Shared/TimeSpanTemplate.cshtml:

```
@model TimeSpan
@{
    TimeSpan initialValue = Model;
}
@string.Format("{0}:{1}", (initialValue.Days * 24) + initialValue.Hours, initialValue.Minutes)

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

This is my model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DisplayName("Varighed")]
public virtual TimeSpan? Duration
{
   get {
      return SolvedDate.HasValue ? (TimeSpan?)SolvedDate.Value.Subtract(ReportedDate) : null;        }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ticket.Duration)
</td>
```

I get this compile formatexception error:

> Input string was not in a correct format. -->
>   "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ticket.Duration)"
>
> System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233033   Message=Input string was not in a correct
>   format.   Source=mscorlib

I have successfully created DateTime-templates for EditViews, but I cant seem to get around this problem on DisplayFor with TimeSpan-types.

I dont have the faintest idea what I am doing, so any clues are appreciated! :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you make your `Duration` property a `TimeSpan` (rather than `TimeSpan?`) does your problem go away?  I suspect this is because your template is declared for `TimeSpan` not `Nullable<TimeSpan>`.

Comment: I think you are right that the nullable part might be a part of the problem.I need the nullable timespan as some records in my database do not have a duration yet.

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting the Ticket from `modelItem` and not `item`? `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Ticket.Duration)`

Comment: It is not really relevant to my question, but no - my foreach loop states 
'@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
}'

Comment: My main question here is - how do I transform my Datetime into a string from my view template without having the format exception error? :)

Comment: to change dateTime format you can just do this
`@Convert.ToDateTime(item.ItemName).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

After reading [How can I String.Format a TimeSpan object with a custom format in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net)

I managed to solve this myself, by outcommenting my TimeSpanTemplate, and simply edit this line in my model from: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

to

`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:%d}d {0:%h}h {0:%m}m {0:%s}s", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to solve this problem, but I think it would be better to use the [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) library.

You would be able to do the following:

```
SolvedDate.Humanize();
```

See here: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-timespan

Comment: I dont really feel like introducing a whole new library to fix this, as it should be a little less complicated to fix.. I think I am missing something simple here.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Timespan is nullable so try:

```
<td>
    @Html.Label("MyTimeSpan", Model.Ticket.Duration != null ? Model.Ticket.Duration.Value : string.Empty)
</td>
```

Comment: I dont think I can just change the DisplayFor to a lable, and I cant figure out the syntax I should use, to get the linq-query modelItem => item.Ticket.Duration into your line..